# JDK 1.8 -XX:+UseLargePages behavior when there's not enough huge pages left on os

Tags: linux, jvm, huge-pages

I am currently confusing how to optimize using HugePages with JVM applications with Netty, **-XX:+UseLargePages** option enabled, and using **G1Gc**.
Also, I didn't forget to set the same max and min size of the heap and metaspace.

My application looks fine, but I was wondering what happens **if there's no remaining free huge pages on system** since JVM uses additional native memory area to allocate direct memory buffer, etc. 
(Assume that application started up normally, and consumes additional HugePages on off-heap memory area.)

I've read following page, but there's no description of the behavior when JVM failed to allocate huge pages.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/largememory-pages.html

I use CentOS 7 and OpenJDK 1.8.0_151-b12 for the testbed before deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If allocating large pages fails, OpenJDK 8 or later falls back to allocating regular pages.

src/hotspot/share/memory/virtualspace.cpp:

```c++
    if (base != NULL) {
[...]
    } else {
      // failed; try to reserve regular memory below
      if (UseLargePages && (!FLAG_IS_DEFAULT(UseLargePages) ||
                            !FLAG_IS_DEFAULT(LargePageSizeInBytes))) {
        log_debug(gc, heap, coops)("Reserve regular memory without large pages");
      }
    }
```

All GC implementations use the `ReservedSpace` helper for allocating memory, so this is not GC-specific.

You can easily test that behavior on Linux by restricting available large pages:

```
$ echo 16 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
$ cat /proc/meminfo  | grep HugePages
AnonHugePages:     40960 kB
HugePages_Total:      16
HugePages_Free:       16
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
$ java -XX:+UseLargePages Test
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 251658240 (errno = 12).
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000707c00000 bytes: 4164943872 (errno = 12).
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 67108864 (errno = 12).
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x0000000000000000 bytes: 67108864 (errno = 12).
$ echo $?
0
```

strace confirms the failed allocation attempt and the successful retry with the same size but without `MAP_HUGETLB`:

```
11631 mmap(NULL, 251658240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
11631 mmap(NULL, 251658240, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7f35d489c000
```